# C++ Read txt file CSV values

Tags: c++, visual-c++, csv, file-io

I know this post has been made before on stack overflow, and I have combined various tutorials; but why does this code cause an error on execution -  it does compile.

```
void leaderBoard::loadFromFile(void)
{
    string line;
    ifstream leaderBoardFile ("leaderboard.data");
    vector<string> playerInfoVector;
    if (leaderBoardFile.is_open())
    {
        while ( leaderBoardFile.good() )
        {
            playerInfoVector.clear();
            getline (leaderBoardFile,line);
            std::string input = line;
            std::istringstream ss(input);
            std::string token;
            //cout << line << endl;

            while(getline(ss, token, ',')) {
                //for current line;
                playerInfoVector.push_back(token);
            }

            string firstName = playerInfoVector.at(0);
            string stringAge = playerInfoVector.at(1);
            string stringScore = playerInfoVector.at(2);

            //int age;
            //stringstream(stringAge) >>    age;
            //int score;
            //stringstream(stringScore) >>  score;
            //addScore(firstName,age,score);
            ////stringstream(stringAge) >> age;

            ////Add text to vector (push back)
            playerInfoVector.clear();
        }
        leaderBoardFile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

Comment: And what error would that be kind sir?

Comment: "First-chance exception at 0x75BFC41F in Labyrinth.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x003EF298."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes loads of times

```
    while ( leaderBoardFile.good() )
    {
        playerInfoVector.clear();
        getline (leaderBoardFile,line);
```

should be

```
    while ( getline (leaderBoardFile,line) )
    {
        playerInfoVector.clear();
```

It is incredible how many times this error is repeated. You actually got it right in your second while loop, so why wrong in the first one?

Unfortunately some tutorials also get this wrong.

It would also be sensible to add a check that you really do have three items in your vector. Something like this

```
        if (playerInfoVector.size() < 3)
        {
            cerr << "Not enough items in player info vector\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        string firstName = playerInfoVector.at(0);
        string stringAge = playerInfoVector.at(1);
        string stringScore = playerInfoVector.at(2);
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. IYHO is it better to clear the vector I have at the start of reading the line, or after reading the line? What would you say is more efficient?

Comment: @ConnorJackson I doubt there's any efficiency difference. At the start seems more logical however.

Comment: See I think after is more logical. Like a chef, you cook something, then clean afterwards.

Comment: @ConnorJackson That's fair enough, it's not a question with a definitely right or wrong answer.